# ActorSelection versus ActorRef - migrating from actorFor to actorSelection

Tags: scala, akka

Akka has deprecated `actorFor` in favor of `actorSelection`.  The former returns an `ActorRef` while the latter returns an `ActorSelection` which could be a collection of `ActorRef`s.

When migrating from `actorFor` to `actorSelection`, you have a couple of optoins:

Option 1: Both `ActorSelection` and `ActorRef` have a `tell` method, so you could almost exchange `actorSelection` for `actorFor` (this is not always true - `ask` is not the same and `actorSelection` could point to multiple `ActorRef`s) so long as there is only one actor for that selection and you are only `tell`ing the actor.

Option 2: Get an `ActorRef` from the `ActorSelection`.  This can be done using either `Identify` (which involves a couple more messages) or `resolveOne` (which involves a `Future`).

In Option 1, what kind of overhead does `ActorSelection` add compared to the `ActorRef` from `actorFor`?

Is there a better option than the ones listed above?

Answer (score 6):

There is overhead for using `ActorSelection` versus `ActorRef`, specifically:

> It is not as performant as with ActorRef, since it has to traverse the
>   hierarchy of actors in the path. If you use remote sends the actor
>   selection traversal will unlikely be the bottleneck, but you have to
>   verify that for your specific usage. We optimized ActorSelection in
>   2.3.x, so it will be faster when you update to that version.

Source: [Post by Patrik Nordwall](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/akka-user/uT6YzFj1sWE/PIwy9ddHqgcJ) on the Akka User list.

Answer (score 0):

In the option 1, the overhead is that the message might be sent to multiple actors instead of just one. If you use wildcards, the actor system will have to identify all the actors matching the actor selection string (some of which are possibly remote), so this might end up being a slower than sending a message to just one specific actor.

However, as long as you don't use wildcards with `actorSelection`, the `ActorSelection` object will refer to at most one actor.

If you want to use the `ask` pattern, you have to first obtain the `ActorRef` using the `Identify` message - there is no better way that option 2.